# Important changes to Apple Push Notification certificates

Tags: iphone, certificate, apple-push-notifications

The production Apple Push Notification service will begin to use a 2048-bit TLS/SSL certificate that provides a more secure connection between your provider server and the Apple Push Notification service.

Can any body explain what is this and what changes we need to make on Server/ iPhone app?

Answer (score 0):

This will not affect anything on your side (as far as your SSL library supports 2048-bit keys/signatures, nearly all modern SSL client libraries do that).